# assign value to variable if id is not available and it is a child element

Tags: javascript, html-table, nested, parent-child

How to assign value to variable through javascript if id is not available and it is a child element

if id is available it is:

```
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
```

but what if id is not available, example the variable table is to be the nested table and the parent tr of this has an id

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="nested-table">
            <td>
                <table> <!--need to assign this as the variable-->
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>    
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following selector:

```
var table = document.querySelector("#nested-table table");
```